# How can I set offset of a video in Swift 4 ? Seek(to:) doesn't seem to work

Tags: swift, avqueueplayer, cmtime, avplayerlooper

I am having an issue setting offset of AVQueuePlayer video. I have tried seek(to function to set offset of the video but it doesn't seem to work. The video always starts from 0 Seconds. Other requirements are playing it with control and looping back which are working fine.

I am kind a stuck at playing the video from any other point other than 0 Seconds.

```
    func getVideoView() -> UIView
    {

    var videoViewContainer = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 375))

    let videoUrl = URL(string: "https://myvideourl.mp4")

    let item = AVPlayerItem(url: videoUrl!)

    player = AVQueuePlayer()

    playerLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: player!, templateItem: item)

    let time =  CMTime(seconds: 17.000000, preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(1))

    player?.seek(to: time, completionHandler: { (handler) in


    } )

    item.forwardPlaybackEndTime = CMTimeMake(20, 1) // For playing it for 20 Seconds

    let layer: AVPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)


    layer.frame = videoViewContainer.bounds

    layer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill

    videoViewContainer.layer.addSublayer(layer)

    player?.play()



    return videoViewContainer
}
```

Comment: Have you tried once with downloaded video?

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer. SeekTo doesn't seem to work when use with AVPlayerLooper.

AVPlayerLooper itself has a property time range.
Example given below

```
    playerLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: self.player!,
                            templateItem: item!, 
                               timeRange: CMTimeRange(start: CMTime(seconds: Double(start), preferredTimescale: 1) , duration: CMTime(seconds: Double(duration), preferredTimescale: 1)))
```